# How did Quantum Field Theory become the dominant understanding of the Standard Model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, education, history

DEspite doing a physics degree somehow QFT missed me entirely until I happened to read about it as the current official standard model in a popular science book, which was rather startling.

At university, we were taught the Standard Model based on particles, and we learnt QM which introduced the idea of waves/wavicles and how they generally look like particles. From popular science on string theory, I understand the idea that a 'particle' is/can be described by an infinite string snaking through space-time which we can only see a cross-section of.

But this is very different from each 'particle' actually being the local value of some field which permeates the whole of space-time. How do we get from one to the other in logical steps? Or how do we get from QFT back to those earlier models?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the history of physics. It would be worth asking on the [History of Science SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JohnRennie I hadn't realised history was OT but I am interested in both aspects so I've reworded this to focus on the physics rather than the history. Edits tor edit requests to improve further are welcome

Comment: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~hooft101/lectures/basisqft.pdf

Comment: The original motivation came from considering a vibrating string. Note that this is unrelated to string theory. The vibrating string is an analogue of a one dimensional field and the approach required to describe it immediately generalises to quantum field theory. This was done by Born and Jordan in (I think) around 1930 so only a few years after the formulation of quantum mechanics. However this is definitely history. If you ask in the HSM SE you should get interesting answers.

Comment: Note that the Standard Model has always been formulated in the language of QFT. If you want a very detailed account of the history of the Standard Model, I recommend the book Inward bound by Abraham Pais.

Comment: *Despite doing a physics degree somehow QFT missed me entirely.* An undergraduate degree in physics does not normally include either quantum field theory or General Relativity (or at least *my* B.S. didn’t include these). They are part of graduate studies when getting an advanced degree such as a Ph.D.

Comment: A particle is not a “local value” of a field.

Comment: This is no longer asking about history. But then you went ahead and closed it anyway despite me putting effort in to edit it.